# Laravel 5.4 scheduler mail not sending but no error logs

Tags: php, laravel, email, smtp

```php
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use App\User;
use Mail;

class SendMail extends Command {
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'users:sendmail';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Command description';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle() {
        $userEmail = User::select('email')->get();

        $emails = [];
        foreach ($userEmail as $each) {
            $emails[] = $each['email'];
        }

        $data = array('name' => "Virat Gandhi");

        \Mail::send(['text' => 'mail'], $data, function ($message) use ($emails) {
            $message->to('xyz@gmail.com', 'Tutorials Point')->subject('Laravel Basic Testing Mail');
            $message->from('demo@xser.net', 'Premium Invoicing System');
        });

        echo "Basic Email Sent. Check your inbox.";
    }
}
?>
```

Cron works but mail does not come, when i hit from route to controller it works, But scheduler does not work, i used the same credentials for browser route hit and scheduler cron jobs

Answer (score 0):

> Yes i tried with log::info. No errors.
> print only scheduler command started and end.
> Cron job works fine
> when i used Gmail credentials it works.
> But i used other credentials it works from browser route, not mail triggered from Cron jobs

Comment: are you using SMTP?